# How to solve textbox text changed event..?

Tags: c#, desktop-application

```
 private void rateTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pieceTextBox.Text))
        {

        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rateReturnTextBox.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            int piece = Convert.ToInt32(pieceTextBox.Text);
            int rate = Convert.ToInt32(rateTextBox.Text);
            int netTotal = piece * rate;
            netTotalBillTextBox.Text = netTotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

//why dose not show the multiplication answer....where is the mistake?
I want this answer in netTotalBillTextBox .

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don't know what you *expect* to happen, we don't know what *actually happens* and we don't see whether it should happen at all (your code).

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(pieceTextBox.Text, out int x) && int.TryParse(rateReturnTextBox.Text, out int y)) netTotalBillTextBox.Text = (x * y).ToString(); else { //do something }`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, in the second condition shouldn't compare `rateTextBox`?

I assume it will always return `string.Empty` in `rateReturnTextBox`.

Comment: int piece = Convert.ToInt32(pieceTextBox.Text);
            int rate = Convert.ToInt32(rateTextBox.Text);
            int netTotal = piece * rate;
            netTotalBillTextBox.Text = netTotal.ToString();
if I use this code it's right?